# Cómo manejar atributos de una clase en una propiedad

Tags: python, python-3.x

Al utilizar los atributos de una clase **en los métodos setter** de las propiedades en Python se genera una excepción AttributeError y quisera saber por qué y cómo solventarlo.

Por ejemplo, al ejecutar:

```
class Clase:
    def __init__(self, surname, foo):
        self.surname = surname
        self.foo = foo

    @property
    def surname(self):
        return self._surname

    @surname.setter
    def surname(self, value):
        self._surname = value + self.foo


cls = Clase("Pérez", "X")
print(cls.surname)
```

Devuelve

```
AttributeError: 'Clase' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

Answer (score 2):

Tal y como tienes tu código, en el inicializador se llama al "setter" de `surname` cuando se hace `self.surname = surname`, esta **llamada se produce antes de que se defina el atributo `foo`** en ese mismo `__init__`, por lo que al ejecutar `self._surname = value + self.foo`, `self.foo` no existe aún.

Lo más sencillo es simplemente definir `foo` antes de `surname`:

```
class Clase:
    def __init__(self, surname, foo):
        self.foo = foo
        self.surname = surname

    @property
    def surname(self):
        return self._surname

    @surname.setter
    def surname(self, value):
        self._surname = value + self.foo
```

Con lo que subtenderías:

```
>>> cls = Clase("Pérez", "X")
>>> print(cls.surname)
PérezX
```